# Drop use of = in parsing arguments in raku

Tags: raku

The fact that you can write in raku the following

```perl
unit sub MAIN(Int $j = 2);

say $j
```

is amazing, and the fact that the argument parsing is done for you is beyond
useful. However I find personally extremely unergonomic
that for such arguments you habe to write a `=` to set the value, i.e.

```
./script.raku -j=5
```

I was wondering if there is a way to tell the parser that it should allow options without
the `=` so that I can write

```
./script.raku -j 5
```

I haven't seen this in the docs and this would really be much more intuitive for some people
like me. If it is not currently possible, I think it would be a useful add-on.

Comment: Fwiw, aiui Raku(do) was improved earlier this year (it claims it was from 2021.03, but I'm not convinced that's right) such that you don't have to write an `=` to set a named arg value. Search for "single named arguments can be separated by spaces too" in the [cli doc page](https://docs.raku.org/language/create-cli).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could also use [SuperMAIN, a library for CLI processing](https://modules.raku.org/dist/SuperMAIN:github:Claudio%20Ramirez%20%3Cpub.claudio@gmail.com%3E). This add some new superpowers to MAIN

Comment: that's actually something I can pretty much use, thanks for that one

Answer (score 8):

There has been a lot of discussion of how command line parameters should be parsed.  At the moment there are no plans of adding more functionality to what Raku provides out of the box.

If you want more tweakability, you should probably look at the [Getopt::Long module](https://modules.raku.org/dist/Getopt::Long:cpan:LEONT) by *Leon Timmermans*

Comment: That's fair enough thanks, I was just curious because I hadn't found anything on the web about it, thanks!